# Implementing a constraint based on previous variable's value in GNU Mathprog/AMPL

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, integer-programming, mathprog

I have a binary program and one of my variables, `x_it` is defined on two sets, being `I: Set of objects` and `T: Set of the weeks of the year`, thus `x_it` is a binary variable standing for whether object `i` is assigned to something on week `t`. The constraint I failed to implement in AMPL/GNU Mathprog is that if `x_it` equals to `1` then `x_i(t+1)` and `x_i(t+2)` also should take value of `1`. Is there a way to implement this constraint in a simple mathematical programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication you want to implement is:

```
 x(i,t) = 1 ==> x(i,t+1) = 1, x(i,t+2) = 1
```

AMPL supports implications (with the ==> operator), so we can write this directly. MathProg does not.

A simple way to implement the implication as straightforward linear inequalities is:

```
x(i,t+1) >= x(i,t)    
x(i,t+2) >= x(i,t)
```

This can easily be expressed in AMPL, MathProg, or any modeling tool.

This is the pure, naive translation of the question. This means however that once a single `x(i,t)=1` all following `x(i,t+1),x(i,t+2),x(i,t+3)..=1`. That could have been accomplished by just the constraint `x(i,t+1) >= x(i,t)`.

A better interpretation would be: we don't want very short run lengths. I.e. patterns: 010 and 0110 are not allowed. This is sometimes called a minimum up-time in machine scheduling and can be modeled in different ways.

1. Forbid the patterns 010 and 0110:

   ```
    (1-x(i,t-1))+x(i,t)+(1-x(i,t+1)) <= 2
    (1-x(i,t-1))+x(i,t)+x(i,t+1)+(1-x(i,t+2)) <= 3
   ```
2. The pattern 01 implies 0111:

   ```
     x(i,t+1)+x(i,t+2) >= 2*(x(i,t)-x(i,t-1))
   ```

Both these approaches will prevent patterns 010 and 0110 to occur.

Comment: But don't you think these constraints eventually lead all of the `x_it` to be 1 ?

Comment: Yes. I will add some different approaches.